# Could anybody help me to fix this error?: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Tags: python-3.x

Code in this picture producing the error.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! We would prefer if you could provide a minimal reproducible example, or just the code in question *as text* (formatted as code) in the question, instead of an image. Having code as text makes it much easier for others to reproduce your error and avoids broken links in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for x in movies['genre'].tolist():
```

Also, you're splitting `x.split(' | ')`. In your example I don't see any spaces between the genres. Only this character `|`. However, if you're expecting spaces between them, then no need to use `' | '`, i.e. spaces on both sides. Just use `'| '`. If no spaces are expected, then `'|'`.

Comment: Yeah I tried and now it is working. Thanks @Rabindra